# Wizard step should work on BACK and CONTINUE buttons

Tags: jquery

I am using a famous Wizard plugin step tab form, here on click CONTINUE button step go-ahead from "Step 1" to "Step 2" and then it stuck. Don't want to work on a tab click.

**[Fiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/adampavlov/v4to02yg/2/)**

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Initialize tooltips
    $('.nav-tabs > li a[title]').tooltip();

    //Wizard
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {

        var $target = $(e.target);

        if ($target.parent().hasClass('disabled')) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    $(".next-step").click(function (e) {

        var $active = $('.wizard .nav-tabs li.active');
        $active.next().removeClass('disabled');
        nextTab($active);

    });
    $(".prev-step").click(function (e) {

        var $active = $('.wizard .nav-tabs li.active');
        prevTab($active);

    });
});

function nextTab(elem) {
    $(elem).next().find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click();
}
function prevTab(elem) {
    $(elem).prev().find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set and remove the `active` class from the `li`

**[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fyrtdLz1/)**

```
$(".next-step").click(function (e) {

    var $active = $('.wizard .nav-tabs li.active');
    $active.next().removeClass('disabled').addClass("active");
    $active.removeClass("active")
    nextTab($active);

});
```